# How to install a bower package using a private git server (SSH)?

Tags: git, ssh, bower, bower-install

**EDIT**: [this guy do exactly the same with success](http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2014/01/using-bower-as-package-management-tool.html), can't figure out why it's not working for me.

I've just installed `git` and setup permissions/SSH authentication with public/private key (Centos 6.5). I'm able to pull/push without problems using i.e.:

```
git clone git@code.organization.com:projects/boilerplate-template
```

Username is `git`, code placed in `/home/git/projects`, repository created with `git --init --shared boilerplate-template`.

How can I require `boilerplate-template` with Bower in another project?

I've tried with the following bower.json file without luck:

```
{
    "name": "my/newproject",
    "dependencies": {
        "boilerplate-template": "git://code.organization.com:projects/boilerplate-template"
    }
}
```

> **ECMDERR**: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads 
>   git://code.organization.com:projects/boilerplate-template, exit code
>   128
>   unable to lookup code.organization.com (port project)...

Sadly it fails  because `:project` is not the port but the path. I've also tried with `ssh://` instead of `git://`:

> **ENOTFOUND**: Package
>   ssh://code.organization.com:projects/boilerplate-template not found.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ok, found the solution here: [Using Bower as the Package Management tool for Internal, Private Libraries](http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2014/01/using-bower-as-package-management-tool.html). Simply remove `git://` or `ssh://` and add `.git` suffix:

```
"git@code.organization.com:projects/boilerplate-template.git#~1"
```

Comment: I got this error 'ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused' and https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/ helped

Comment: Any idea where bower looks for your private key on windows?

Comment: In the user .ssh folder

Comment: wow, bower.json not same syntaxe than package.json....love front end!

Answer (score 11):

Also, if you're using Github and Bower for a private repo you can create a `.netrc` file if you need to run `bower install` on a remote server.

e.g. You have a DO droplet and need to checkout a git repo that uses ssh keys, but needs to run `bower install` with some deps that are private. If you add the `.netrc` file to your remote machine you will be good to go for deploys/builds.

```
// .netrc where someToken is generated in Github under Personal access token
machine github.com
    login userName
    password someToken
```

Answer (score 9):

I had trouble getting `bower login` working, so I went with this approach. `<TOKEN>` is generated [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens). It works for private repositories hosted on Github.

```
"dependencies": {
    "your-package": "https://<TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Account/Repository.git"
}
```

Comment: Some of the other methods did not work on different machines in my office but this one worked consistently! (thankyou!!!)

Answer (score 6):

TeamCity had this issue for us when trying to download a private repo from GitHub. In case this helps anyone we solved it by using SSH and providing a [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) by running `bower login` before `bower install`:

Example dependency in bower.json:

```
"repository": "git@github.com:Account/Repository.git"
```

Commands to run within build script:

```
bower login -t {GitHub Personal Access Token}
bower install
```

Answer (score 3):

go to https://github.com/settings/tokens, generate your token

```
bower login -t {your token} 

bower install
```

Comment: This won't work: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2317#issuecomment-230050330

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, setting the package location to:

```
"git@code.organization.com:projects/yourproject.git"
```

Will allow bower to pull from a git repository.

If you get an SSH issue on Windows you can follow these steps:

1. Download the PuTTY tools
2. Use PuttyGen to generate a new key.
3. Save the private key to your users .ssh folder as `anything.ppk`
4. Copy the text starting `ssh-rsa` in putty gen to the clipboard
5. Go to github and `Settings -> SSH keys -> Add SSH key` giving your key a title and pasting the text from PuttyGen in to the key portion
6. Add an environment variable named `GIT_SSH` with the value being the path to the Putty tool PLINK.exe e.g. `C:\Program Files\Putty\PLINK.exe`
7. Run the Putty tool "Pageant.exe" then add your `anything.ppk` key to pageant (you can add a shortcut to your startup folder with `C:\pathtopageant\pageant.exe C:\Users\myuser\.ssh\anything.ppk` to automatically add the key to pageant on startup)
8. Open `putty.exe` itself, enter your github enteprise hostname (code.organization.com in the above example), or "github.com" in the hostname textbox and click "Open". You will probably be prompted to trust the host, click yes to add it to your known_hosts file as bower is unable to do this on first run and would have just hung
9. Finally run `bower install`!

Answer (score 2):

I ended with following, although working only for private github repos.

1. Generate Github access token [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and set it as environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN`
2. Define shorthand resolver in `.bowerrc`:

   ```
   "shorthand_resolver": "https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/{{owner}}/{{package}}.git"
   ```
3. Now I can add my dependency as `bower install me/my-private-package` or list it in `bower.json`:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "my-private-package": "me/my-private-package"
   }
   ```

Works also for Heroku builds.

Answer (score 1):

You might face this issue if you are cloning from a private repo as well.
The accepted answer is correct, however I want to clarify this concern:

1. if you have github SSH access to your machine, go to the git repo and copy the "clone with SSH" link, then place it inside the bower.json file.
2. if you have https(login authentication) setup for github on your machine, copy the "clone with https" link, then place it inside the bower.json file.
   repository

Example:
SSH link: git@github.com:Account/Repository.git
HTTPS link: https://github.com/Account/Repository.git

Bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": { 
 "repository": "paste SSH/HTTPS clone line here"
}
```